# Operations with list of numbers via InputField

Tags: string-manipulation, inputfield

How do you input a list of numbers via `InputField` and immediately generate their sum (or whatever other operation involving a list of numbers) underneath.

I've tried with `ImportString`:

```
DynamicModule[{x}, Column[{InputField[Dynamic[x], String, ContinuousAction -> True], Dynamic[Activate@Plus[Delete[#, 0] &@ImportString[x, "List"]]]}]]
```

Also with `ToExpression`:

```
Column[{InputField[Dynamic[x], String, ContinuousAction -> True], Dynamic[xNum = ImportString[x, "List"]], Dynamic[Activate@Plus@Delete[xNum, 0]]}]
```

Neither one works...

Comment: Try `DynamicModule[{x = "", xc = {}}, Column[{InputField[Dynamic[x], String, ContinuousAction -> True], Dynamic[xc = ImportString[x, "List", "LineSeparators" -> ","]], Dynamic[Total[xc]]}]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression) after adding "{" and "}" (I also removed trailing commas):

```
DynamicModule[{x=""},
    Column[{
        InputField[Dynamic[x], String, ContinuousAction->True],
        Dynamic[Total @ ToExpression["{"<>StringTrim[x,","]<>"}"]]
    }]
]
```

Here is a short animation:

[image]